# How to correctly bind toolbook options to a menu option?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a menu with two custom options : OptionA and Option B

My objective is to get two toolbook options, A1 and A2, when clicking OptionA on the menubar

This is my code (mainly taken from minimum sample in wxWidgets repo):

```
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override;
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();

private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void onOptionA(wxCommandEvent& event);

    wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);
    wxToolbook* tabControl1 = new wxToolbook(panel, wxID_ANY, {10, 10}, {370, 250}, /*wxTBK_BUTTONBAR|*/wxTBK_HORZ_LAYOUT);

    wxNotebookPage* tabA1 = new wxNotebookPage(tabControl1, wxID_ANY);
    wxNotebookPage* tabA2 = new wxNotebookPage(tabControl1, wxID_ANY);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1,
    ID_OptionA = 2
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_OptionA, MyFrame::onOptionA)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "MyPrj")
{

    if (wxPlatformInfo::Get().GetOperatingSystemFamilyName() == "Windows") tabControl1->SetImageList(new wxImageList(16, 16));
    else if (wxPlatformInfo::Get().GetOperatingSystemFamilyName() == "Macintosh") tabControl1->SetImageList(new wxImageList(32, 
32));
    else tabControl1->SetImageList(new wxImageList(24, 24));

    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);

    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");

    wxMenu *menuOptionA = new wxMenu;
    wxMenu *menuOptionB = new wxMenu;

    menuBar->Append(menuOptionA, "&A");
    menuBar->Append(menuOptionB, "&B");

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to myPrj!");

    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);


    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, [&](wxCommandEvent& event) {
        tabControl1->AddPage(tabA1, "A1", true, 0);
        tabControl1->AddPage(tabA2, "A2", false, 1);
    }, ID_OptionA);

}


void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::onOptionA(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA1, "A1", true, 0);
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA2, "A2", false, 1);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

With :

```
Bind(wxEVT_MENU, [&](wxCommandEvent& event) {
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA1, "A1", true, 0);
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA2, "A2", false, 1);
}, ID_OptionA);
```

when clicking OptionA on the menu, I do not get the two toolmenu options A1 and A2

If I remove `ID_OptionA` :

```
Bind(wxEVT_MENU, [&](wxCommandEvent& event) {
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA1, "A1", true, 0);
    tabControl1->AddPage(tabA2, "A2", false, 1);
});
```

I strangely get the two toolbook options A1 and A2 when clicking File->Hello

What do I have to add and / or modify in order to make A1 and A2 appear when clicking "Option A" on the menu?

Comment: your code seems weird - why do you use both event table AND dynamic event binding? Use one or the other. Also IF you want to use Bind(), you should pass eventSink parameter.

Comment: You are right @Igor . That was one of the mistakes I made.  I solved in this way: I removed the Bind() while keeping the Event Table, and added this line : `menuOptionA->Append(ID_OptionA, "OptionA");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as already noted in comments, you need to use *either* `Bind()` *xor* event tables, but not both in the same window as this is at best confusing.

Second, you do need to specify the ID when handling menu events. If you call `Bind()` without it, you're handling all menu events in your handler, which is probably not what you want (although you could do this and then examine `event.GetId()` inside the handler to decide what to do if you really wanted). If you call `Bind()` with the ID, as you show, it does work and your event handler will get called if you don't have anything else connecting to it too (and executing first).